# Free project hosting site easily integrated with Hudson/Maven etc

Tags: maven-2, hudson, project-hosting

I want to host my java project on a free project hosting site.
I want to use SVN (if possible integrated in NetBeans).

I want the site to be easy to use and offer an option like Hudson system to control my nightly build/test execution.

Is there such a site(s) ?

Thank you in advance for the answers.

If there is an alternative that you think it's better than the SVN or something else, please use enough argumentation to convince me. I accept any proposals that you have tried out.

Answer (score 4):

> I want the site to be easy to use and offer an option like Hudson system to control my nightly build/test execution.

Hosted Continuous Integration for Java is not something easy to provide for free by nature (because it's very CPU and disk intensive), so you won't find that on "big" public forges.

The only place I know that offers CI (and subversion, mailing list, wiki, etc) is [CodeHaus.org](http://codehaus.org/). Might be an option if your project is "eligible".

If not, either run Hudson yourself (and just plug it on any hosted Subversion repository, e.g. on Google Code) or... use a commercial service like [CloudBees](http://cloudbees.com/), [MikeCI](http://www.mikeci.com/), [CI Foundry](http://cifoundry.net/). See also [Hosted Continuous Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380721/hosted-continuous-integration).

Comment: yup (+1), installing hudson is not hard (although on windows it may turn out to be ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Actually my question was something like a consulting 2 questions.
Here are my answers to them.

1. Find SVN free source control repository

   - I have stopped on two options:

     - **Java.net** - this seems like a repository with future and it's getting upgraded with Kenai technology, so I hope it's stable and fast.
     - **kenai.com** - Very nice looking integration with NetBeans! Easy to use and with lots of features like integrated issue-reporting. Unfortunately, this one is dead and projects are getting migrated to **java.net**. So stick with the first proposition.
2. Integrate with Hudson

   - I haven't installed and configured a Hudson yet, but I guess it won't be such a problem. We'll see.